# dotnet --list-runtimes or dotnet --info is showing two entries for runtime

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I installed .NET core 3.1.22 hosting bundle on one of my server and post-installation when I run dotnet --info or dotnet --list-runtimes commands in command prompt, I get two entries for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 both pointing to the same folder "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.22"
Should this be an issue?

If yes, has anybody else faced this and how to resolve it ?
Note : I see same results for .NET core 3.1.20 and 3.1.19

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please show us the complete output of the two commands so we can get a better idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think this is the issue which is related with the dotnet sdk, I suggest you could try to download the newest version for the dotnet SDK and try again.

SDK download link:https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1

Besides, this will not affect the host bundle usage when you hosting your asp.net core application.